# How can I find solution for $\cos{2x(\sqrt{\cos x}\ +\ \sqrt{\sin x})\ =\ \cos^8x\ -\ \sin^8x\ }$

Tags: trigonometry

This is my Math problem
$$
    \cos{2x(\sqrt{\cos x}\ +\ \sqrt{\sin x})\ =\ \cos^8x\ -\ \sin^8x\ }
$$
I tried to here:
$$
   {\sqrt{\cos x}\ +\ \sqrt{\sin x})\ =\ \cos^4x\ +\ \sin^4x\ }
$$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have edited  my post. I'm sorry about my unclear post.

Comment: $\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x$ and not $\cos^4 x -\sin^4 x$.

Comment: @Gary If cos^4x - sin^4x = (cos^2x - sin^2x)(cos^2x + sin^2x) = cos2x*1 = cos2x right?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand your expression. As written, it would be $$\cos(2)\cdot  x\cdot \left(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}\right),$$ is it what you want to write ? Or you want rather say $$\cos(2x)\cdot \left(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}\right)\ \ ?$$ Or $$\cos\Big(2x(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x})\Big)\ \ ?$$

Comment: @Surb sorry if my expression is misunderstood. I am from Vietnam and we use like above

Comment: @ViệtAnh: But what do you want to say among the 3 expression I wrote in my previous comment ?

Comment: I mean cos(2x). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The OP's work is correct because $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ is cancelled out.

Comment: @ViệtAnh You can learn how to use MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Don't forget to put dollar signs at the beginning and at the end like this: \$x^2\$ becomes $x^2$.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you. I will try to improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Now, or $$\cos2x=0$$ or
$$\sqrt{\cos{x}}+\sqrt{\sin{x}}=\cos^4x+\sin^4x.$$
But, $$\sqrt{\cos{x}}+\sqrt{\sin{x}}\geq\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1\geq\cos^4x+\sin^4x,$$
which gives $$(\sin{x},\cos{x})=(1,0)$$ or
$$(\sin{x},\cos{x})=(0,1).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: THanks for your answer. I learnt a lot from your support.

Comment: @Việt Anh You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have derived $\cos2x=\cos^4x-\sin^4x$

What if  $\cos2x=0?$

Otherwise we need $\cos x,\sin x\ge0$ right?

Now if $0\le b\le1,$

for $m-n>0$

$$ b^m-b^n=b^n(b^{m-n}-1)\le0$$  right?

Comment: cos2x = 0 i did solved it. However, I am not really what are your --Hint-- from cosx,sinx >=0 to the end. Could you explain more clearly

Comment: @ViệtAnh,  Observe that here $$0\le\cos x\le1,\cos^4x-\cos^{1/2}x=\cos^{1/2}x(\cos^{4-1/2}x-1)\le0$$  right? So, when does the  following equality hold  $$\cos^4x+\sin^4x=\cos^{1/2}x+\sin^{1/2}x$$

Comment: I understand now. Many Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

The OP's work is correct because:

$$(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)(\sqrt{\cos x} +\sqrt{\sin x})= (\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x)(\cos^4 x- \sin^4 x) $$
$$(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)(\sqrt{\cos x} +\sqrt{\sin x})= (\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x)(\cos^2 x- \sin^2 x)(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x) $$

and then the terms cancel.

Notice that for all real $x$, $\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = (\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)^2 - 2 \cos^2 x \sin^2 x ≤ 1$.

Meanwhile, $\sqrt{\cos x} + \sqrt{\sin x} ≥ 1$. This can be proved using Michael Rozenberg's answer.

You also have to check for the case when $\cos 2x = 0$. In this case there are no extranous solutions. Therefore the solution is $x = 2n \pi, x = 2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Just a tip: you can wait before accepting an answer, since other answers might come after you accept one answer.